# Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages ERROR

Tags: bug-reporting

Recently  I had problems regarding my software center so I decided to uninstall it . But when I tried to install using the following command sudo apt-get install software-center*. I get the following error -
 " The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ubuntu-kylin-software-center : Depends: language-pack-zh-hans but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages. " So can anyone help me with this problem .

Comment: What release version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 14.04 release version

Answer (score -1):

I think your apt cache is broken somehow, if you have problem with apt-cache you'll have problem with installation.
Open terminal and try this

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

And follow the instruction if any like

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get install -f
```

This will check for any updates/upgrades, hopefully fix your system. After that run

`sudo apt-get install software-center*`

This will install Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: Now it is showing the error - 
" The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ubuntu-kylin-software-center : Depends: language-pack-zh-hans but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages."

How do i resolve it ?

Comment: ubuntu-kylin-software-cente ?

Comment: Yep It says that